# Markdown for recognizing url without http://

Tags: php, parsing, markdown

I'd like to extend [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#autolink) such that urls minus the `http://` get converted into links.

Currently you have to write http://my-site.com/ to get the url whereas I'd prefer just to write `mysite.com`.

This requires a regex solution, correct? And why didn't Gruber originally introduce this?

I'm using [this Markdown library which is a faithful reproduction of Gruber's syntax in PHP.](https://github.com/michelf/php-markdown)

Comment: An [URL](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986) has a specification including the `scheme://`. Without that it's not an URL. Nitpicking, but still :)

Comment: Why close this question? I asked two questions which have objective answers.

Comment: For other newbies, `scheme` is also referred to as `protocol`.

Comment: I am not the person who voted to close, but as far as I can see I only see one objective question (the reason why Gruber didn't do something is not objective unless Gruber himself comes to answer here - which is unlikely). On top of that, the other question is a trivial question with an answer that has no real use - it' __no__.

Comment: @nightcracker fair enough.